# What's the proper name for the vector encoding that encodes "3.5" as "[1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0, ..., 0]"?

Tags: machine-learning, math

Doing an ML thing yesterday, my team found that we wanted to encode some numbers into vectors consisting of run of 1s with length equal to the whole part, plus one more element for the fractional part, plus some number of padding 0s.  Thus for example the number 3.5 is unpacked into a vector like so: `[1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0, ..., 0]` (it makes sense in context, I promise).  So, now we have some functions for packing and unpacking numbers to and from this representation and we want to name them in the standard way, only we can't figure out what that is.

This is a little bit like a one-hot encoding, but it's not *that* similar: we have multiple hot bits and also usually one warm bit.  It's a lot like a unary number representation, except for the fractional part and the padding zeroes.  In practice the implementation is just a vector fill.  None of these connections are getting me anywhere on Google.

This representation is natural enough in our domain that I'm sure we're not the first people to think of it, so there must be some prior art somewhere.  But where?

Comment: What's the limit for these kind of numbers?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans we're only interested in numbers between 0 and 366.

Comment: So it's always a 366 element vector, but it's right-padded with zeroes instead of left-padded, so that every element has to be a float, rather than only the last element? (if so, please remember to put those details in the post). Because if it were left-padded, it'd be "a weird kind of X dot Y" format, where your X is 366 instead of 9, and your Y is 1 even though it's _actually_ your number of floating precision bits. (For example, a 16.16 format is a 32 bit value where the first 16 bits encode an integer, and the last 16 bits encode the integer numerator of a ½¹⁶ fraction)